# Get text after needle?

Tags: php, string

If i had the following text in a string:

```
<h4>Tom</h4>
<p>One Paragraph</p>
<p>Two Paragraph</p>
```

What code would i need to parse on that string to get an output like this (if i didnt know what was inside the `<h4>` tag?

```
 <p>One Paragraph</p>
 <p>two Paragraph</p>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You beed to use the "code" button for HTML, when you use the quote button, markdown will eat your HTML markup.

Comment: No problem. Can you be more specific what the needle exactly is in this case? Any h4 tag? A h4 tag with "Tom" in it? How far after the needle does the text need to go?

Comment: Well i dont know whats going to be in the h4 tag, nor do i know how far it needs to go - to the end of the string?

Comment: well, you would need to know where it ends. ie, the next pattern that you want it to stop.

Comment: If you want some "code" you should specify which programming language you are willing to use...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [stripios](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) to get the start of `</h4>`. Add the length of `</h4>` to the offset and then use [substr](https://www.php.net/substr) to get all text after the offset.

Example:

```
$str = '....Your string...';
$offset = stripos($str, '</h4>');
if ( $offset === false ){
    //error, end of h4 tag wasn't found
}
$offset += strlen('</h4>');
$newStr = substr($str, $offset);
```

I should point out that if the HTML gets any more complex or you don't control the HTML, you may want to use a [HTML parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). It is much more robust and less likely to fail if it (for example) encounters `< /h4 >` rather than `</h4>`. However, in this case it is overkill.

Comment: +1 if the task is really that limited, that's the best way to go.

Answer (score 12):

You can use [`strstr`](http://php.net/strstr) to get the substring starting with `</h4>` and remove the `</h4>` with [`substr`](http://php.net/substr):

```
$needle = '</h4>';
$rest = substr(strstr($string, $needle), strlen($needle));
```

Since PHP 5.3 you can also specify the third parameter *before_needle* with *true*:

```
$rest = strstr($string, $needle, true);
```

Another way would be to use [`explode`](http://php.net/explode):

```
list(,$rest) = explode($needle, $string, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless the sample HTML you've posted is particularly representative of your data set, you may find it easier and more reliable to use an HTML parser such as [this one](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

HTML is notoriously difficult to parse reliably (technically, impossible) with regular expressions, and the parser will give you a very simple means to find the nodes you're interested in.

If the above HTML is all you're interested in then you can craft an appropriate regexp. For anything more general I'd explore the parser route.

Comment: For all HTML parsing issues I would recommend using a DOM class. There is a good one builtin, but probably way to powerfull for this particular problem. 
The problem with using something like strstr or the string routines is that they will fail as soon as the HTML structure changes.

+1 for the comment of using a HTML parser / DOM Class.

Comment: You mean I didn't get the +1 for the Zappa Gravatar ?