# How to get String after needle in PHP?

Tags: php

I have string like below:

```
$str = '/test/test1/test2/test3/testupload/directory/';
```

now I want to fetch some specific string so tried:

```
strstr($str, 'test3');
```

But I want to fetch value after needle?  How can i do?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get text after needle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216710/get-text-after-needle)

Comment: why not spliting the string and then picking last values of array ?

Comment: @BhumiShah is none of the answers correct or helpful here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = '/test/test1/test2/test3/testupload/directory/';        
$new_str = strstr($str, 'test3');
// Use this to get string after test3 
$new_str = str_replace('test3', '', $new_str); 
// $new_str value will be '/testupload/directory/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Can also be done with preg_match()

```
preg_match("/test3\/(.*)/", $str, $output);
Echo $output[1];
```

With preg_match it's a one line job to get the part you want.
The pattern searches for `test3` and a `/` after, but because `/` needs to be escaped there is `\/`.
Then the `(.*)` means match everything till end of string.
Output[0] will be the full match "test3/testupload...".
Output[1] is only the part you want"testupload/...".

Answer (score 1):

Why not construct a helper function.

Here's one I made earlier (totally not an Art Attack reference).

```
/**
 * Return string after needle if it exists.
 *
 * @param string $str
 * @param mixed $needle
 * @param bool $last_occurence
 * @return string
 */
function str_after($str, $needle, $last_occurence = false)
{
    $pos = strpos($str, $needle);

    if ($pos === false) return $str;

    return ($last_occurence === false)
        ? substr($str, $pos + strlen($needle))
        : substr($str, strrpos($str, $needle) + 1);
}
```

You may have noticed, this function gives you the option to return contents after the first or last occurrence of the given needle. So here's a couple of use cases:

```
$animals = 'Animals;cat,dog,fish,bird.';

echo str_after($animals, ','); // dog,fish,bird.

echo str_after($animals, ',', true); // bird.
```

I tend to create a global `helpers.php` file containing functions similar to this, I recommend you do the same - it makes things so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out index of `test3` and then proceed:

```
<?php
$str = '/test/test1/test2/test3/testupload/directory/';
$find = 'test3'; // Change it to whatever you want to find.
$index = strpos($str, $find) + strlen($find);
echo substr($str, $index); // Output: /testupload/directory/
?>
```

Or explode() the array with `test3` and find out last element.

```
<?php
$str = '/test/test1/test2/test3/testupload/directory/';
$find = 'test3'; // Change it to whatever you want to find.
$temp = explode($find, $str);
echo end(explode($find, $str));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php
$str = '/test/test1/test2/test3/testupload/directory/';
$position = stripos($str, "test3");
if ($position !== false) {
    $position += strlen("test3");
    $newStr = substr($str, $position);
    echo "$newStr";
} else {
    echo "String not found";
}
?>
```